# change the dates in two place in a text

Tags: powershell

Looking to change `yyyy,MM,dd` to user input date. Similarly looking to change `abcd,ef,gh` also to user input date. `abcd,ef,gh` gets succesfully converted to the date user inputs. However, `yyyy,MM,dd` stays the same.

Here is the data in the output text file:

```
(Global History"&customer=guest&password=guest&STARTTIME=yyyy,MM,dd,00,00,00&STOPTIME=abcd,ef,gh,00,00,00&POINTSEVERY=15 min&GRAPHTYPE=excel)
```

Here is the script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

$form.Text = "Select a From Date" 
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(243,230) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$calendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
$calendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$calendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$form.Controls.Add($calendar) 

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(38,165)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(113,165)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$form.Topmost = $True

$result = $form.ShowDialog() 

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
  Remove-Item H:\oim\adcbsm007\karthik.txt
  $path = "H:\oim\adcbsm007\adcbsm007.txt"
  $word1 = "yyyy,MM,dd"
  $replacement = $calendar.SelectionStart
  $text1 = Get-Content $path
  $newText = $text -replace $word, $replacement.ToString('yyyy,MM,dd')
  $newText > "H:\oim\adcbsm007\karthik.txt"

  $result = $form.ShowDialog()
  if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $path = "H:\oim\adcbsm007\adcbsm007.txt"
    $word = "abcd,ef,gh"
    $replacement2 = $calendar.SelectionStart
    $text = Get-Content $path
    $newText = $text2 -replace $word, $replacement.ToString('yyyy,MM,dd')
    $newText > "H:\oim\adcbsm007\karthik.txt"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

You initialize the variables `$word1` and `$text1`, but then you try to replace `$word` in `$text`:

```
$word1 = "yyyy,MM,dd"
$replacement = $calendar.SelectionStart
$text1 = Get-Content $path
$newText = $text -replace $word, $replacement.ToString('yyyy,MM,dd')
```

Replace the line

```
$newText = $text -replace $word, $replacement.ToString('yyyy,MM,dd')
```

with

```
$newText = $text1 -replace $word1, $replacement.ToString('yyyy,MM,dd')
```

and the code should do what you expect.